# Memory Fragmentation from reading file in Embedded System

Tags: c++, embedded-linux

I have a configuration text file on an embedded system with a Linux OS.
Requirements are that the file is text, and the embedded system has
32 Megabytes of dynamic ram.  The app. that will read the file is coded in C++.

The file could be read using a method like this.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

ifstream infile ("config_file_path");    
if (infile.good())
{
    string line;   
    // Set capacity to length of the longest line.
    const unsigned char maxLen = 100;

    line.reserve (maxLen);

    while (std::getline (infile, line))
    { 
        // Process the data in the line.
        processData (line);
    }
}
```

Would heap fragmentation be an issue for this implementation?
The file can have up to about 150 lines of text to read.

Comment: You could use a string with a custom allocator, so that you allocate the memory the way you want to

Comment: What kind of issue do you expect? 32 Mb is a pretty big chunk of memory. But to avoid any fragmentation, i would suggest to allocate a chunk which would be the size of the file and load it (unbuffered, with 'read') with the contents of the file. Forget about 'strings', use 'char *'

Comment: Depends on lifetime of this code. If it is executed once and ends quickly - probably, no issue. If you need high robustness and availability - Keep It Simple.

Comment: Given that you are always reading in the same string and you expect the longest line to be shorter than your reserved size, there should be just one allocation at the beginning, so I don't expect particular problems.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I'll consider loading a char array with the file's content and working with that. I was concerned about string allocations on the heap, after reading some content online where the author recommending against this for embedded devices.  But we have a rather large amount of memory.

Comment: @Mattz *"I'll consider loading a char array with the file's content and working with that"* -- You could accomplish that with just one **mmap()** of the file into the process' virtual memory.

Comment: Thanks. I read the linux page for mmap, and that method looks promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would heap fragmentation be an issue for this implementation?

In the displayed sample I can't identify a line that would indicate heap fragmentation.

You are using `std::string` object whose internal mechanisms are considered generally unpredictable, i.e. how big the object will grow and when it will deallocate memory and that's it.

- As a first step consider [`std::string::capacity`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/capacity/) to ensure more compact memory.
- As a second step consider providing [custom allocators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator), specific alternatives to the general free store (heap) are: *Pool* and *Stack*.
- As a final step consider using less abstract code, i.e. pointers, arrays, etc, which is the inevitable solution when you are closer to the hardware. especially when you are using the object just to extract input and pass as parameter, i.e. no use of any of the `std::string` specific member functions, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The individual string's capacity never changes when a large enough amount is reserved.  I'll consider making a custom allocator and a char array to hold the data and char pointers to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

it is hard to say if your app suffers from memory fragmentation from your code. (your code might add some fragmentation but i do not know how critical it is)
you can try to use non-standard malloc libraries - 
jemalloc
nedmalloc
tcmalloc
they might give you better objects layout as well as an ability to dump the memory layout

general approach:

check if the app can get "not enough memory". stress test might help. 
 check how much free memory your app has and how fragmented it is.
 if the fragmentation is the issue - try the following:
 heap loves LIFO principle (delete the last created block). try to keep variables on stack. use specialized allocators.

in case of your function:

in order to minimize heap pressure, you can try to read lines into a stack buffer (e.g. using fgets)

Comment: Thanks for the info. A stack buffer is a good idea to hold the data. This has not been implemented yet. I was concerned about minimizing heap usage.